# Specify balance during wallet creation in PAB simulator

Tags: plutus, simulator, pab, plutus-starter

Using the PAB Simulator from the plutus-starter (version 1.0.9, commit: a85818c27926f34d627225636f463cc6698706fc), I'm getting some odd behavior in terms of wallet creation.

I've created a simple contract (GiftContract) and use a shell script to create four wallets. I have not changed the main function within the pab/Main.hs.

Yet, I am getting this output after shutting down the PAB via hitting return.

```
[INFO]     {, ""}: 59999999960
[INFO] Wallet 36cb1d44654c33ed6b26cbe2da0848de2ebfdb20010679a06c5f609c474f349b8003380446e9159a34504f9fd19da3e93f215efa30cae9455d441be0eac8db66291a5a5e8c961f9da5fb8cb616ab630a6600f4a44acd520fa701b330849e4446d7d1711ac606ae93a2b3d457dd7f4f36b3af92dd0de82a7caf471fb5ed2b5ea3: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet 3e983a2291ed95a079bfbbf1c447180c90241c6eb288ca1d7fa9f3a4f1f4879e1d5b3a2dcc7f6a4207c71987e38a66172d5111c8ef874408f786cafba51a74fc2b68037bbb9a4507f9268eea9fc89e8035fa867020d74f16bc9dc65cc8bd876798585d84f5bd641ec9fa6e44be139edbbab1d6fefb42a303415903e79fe19738: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 10000000000
[INFO] Wallet 562f269ac4ce35c9be75343cb9d76b3149d1ea5a509299204de6b61dfec1908ec7a4aeed5057be46ff9881d276f9b4050acf9fbc68b61708e33f64db34f479bddd497ff6d3a59aadc10782de888dc139213f444fe7af7b469cab15d50e1cb6d58fba680762c1963f345178e1a7daf62c2eac026b62ceba08c1c5020326d75c20: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet 7628f55f34ca6d864c05aae491e67a5cc0998c4e9461d716fa728fefa837058e3adcc42d910d0404fbddaa157f4d0869f2863faf6cc706eae8eafd204af69a33bd3f819a795f4f7388759a4355436e7bddebbdc14a903df8e4ee733d98616cade35c741d39593e68ea7e331bb145f032cf704ed6d1324d9647ecc1aaaee4f7e8: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet 76d5e1291d51f16eb442267faccd0ab51a3b0c4a21eb6b8f72d5f0a4ca467189ac5f70a018c6df3f632b48fd8ead1b68f39a44de06f5a5de42a6a131af0f085d44becd56fa30041efea5ff2637205181837dffd03545d3db1c11e6dcbbd3415ce8f85aad41776b99eb62a797b8c5abbe82061e1634efc4c7d5ac6fff3ca94d7f: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet 7e203f38109d82c064e95ff2008d84cf6f5c95ec5dbea86d24f407011f65e3868232a16b2bdab56ccff3ab77e24b6a5c88291dd6519b32943fe85ec52c7e6ffe4ab780e3653ceefb79a9e697805ccd430501b09b9a932def195173d96c91013c8b2e8b948109b07a0cae8725f7a8b2b4a892954971891425b4ef3b2eec05f9a1: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet 86c4c1d06a6cd0480865a836fafd97daeba7c79bdc043dff34f9d4553c026e831a4a36760c1d8a0a5458efcb33394ce936b139549570e0f2e80739d50abb6402fcd5201fc11e20cdba72c7440a5e406d314cd1f63fa1d87c83881e0dc1fe3ac5bf6f6a576cf7c56f8d46926bcd24b7de630455a7df7cebb0afadce72d1ede55c: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet 86c6ea24ce790fd9e422a3d22fa6cbc4cf72802675f40b8e2783b4cf38bd4a89a20ee5f32e19499768d274044f825d7251d2bf05c0ce85bfd183127b87376acf115f3ee432684888a2a7b059ba6bffedded97918daf53582e3790082d62856450d8e0efdd7e7b81bcba6c333bb10af271637a9c781d8788db7dc8a8a30763b7e: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 10000000000
[INFO] Wallet b6d40a76f3fd73233a7e0c52a1bb99174151b3643f462016b8b39f776acd4081429729fd15129139332ede3e94ac805090d6e80b78e187ea85c29012c7b4f4b6e9929aa98f85a5d3173cfc128f4198c437ee3484f676ae741412698a00603111c2b887a0b36c23620aca53026dddc27a4c078aec919e739e2b81bb2f729c5943: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet c6794804ca7d19368487af2aa7324296b34274cc69137d1c6187b18a2cb2ce873cb2519aee42967cb4e9661fb3cd106dd68158f16bdfc9b4da04046d06c9d5accaafea24be9b96b417e47d713c3481db821bce2dab3d4bee156d4ef80b249310f227a7eaefdc7a311ea4c93437610d16b02119e4300778573d96107e829035d7: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 10000000000
[INFO] Wallet ce5bf0869d6720212e4dcf3ea6992cf4a9b88c39261fd9d6a635f046a17da49b6125ba6748c542e5821ec9d1e9d2f0564bc7572c1ec0e1a82cce88951dec70639e228ed6586bd2946247d66f88fac7e266a9cf37ab49ef1b9b17befd34a3db085e5af768f7297f0e1138220378a2d13c470da5a79639d8313911adeb0436d91e: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet e6778caeed9911d9b0b49f4fd026052395b6b7025b016052c7ca937e8f332e82338bbe4abdb5d91b348b8361c04117e538f8e6c98f716354837ec822b970419f61636d94a191bc8efbe1e7b53ef59d7b77c67adeb5a3f11fe754ee5ce407045f0da5b9850ac337f62d3bacbbd5ec336736dcb26dcebdea6fb5620b3e4837d177: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 100000000000
[INFO] Wallet e6a9e1d3c75218fe4658682642498ddc2de21d4c852985d86aa574642e4aa98332ee626af31520ec3a6425bfb19492f04bdf09e0a1c9d17c32712870f4649acc8c6ef7b2d2ac09cfbdf8b9894393f8cfd6375a9380864d7003dd52c022e81b449459eccd92f62fb1797abf4dd421772635497fd195a4fd0263a4f1c0d4f64f3c: 
[INFO]     {, ""}: 10000000000
```

As you can see, we have our 10 regular wallets with a balance of 100,000,000,000 lovelaces each. Yet, there is also three wallets with a balance of 10,000,000,000 lovelaces each and a wallet of 59,999,999,960 lovelaces. The sum of those last wallets minus 4 * 10 lovelaces fee (for creation?) would add up to 100,000,000,000 lovelaces (the value of one default simulator wallet), but it is not intuitive nor did I find any documentation on this behavior.

I have followed the repo's readme to create the wallets and activate the contracts in this manner:

```
#1/bin/sh
export W1=`curl -s -d '' http://localhost:9080/wallet/create | jq '.wiWallet.getWalletId'`
export W2=`curl -s -d '' http://localhost:9080/wallet/create | jq '.wiWallet.getWalletId'`
export W3=`curl -s -d '' http://localhost:9080/wallet/create | jq '.wiWallet.getWalletId'`
export W4=`curl -s -d '' http://localhost:9080/wallet/create | jq '.wiWallet.getWalletId'`


export W1_IID=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"caID": "GiftContract", "caWallet":{"getWalletId": '$W1'}}' http://localhost:9080/api/contract/activate | jq .unContractInstanceId | tr -d '"')
export W2_IID=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"caID": "GiftContract", "caWallet":{"getWalletId": '$W2'}}' http://localhost:9080/api/contract/activate | jq .unContractInstanceId | tr -d '"')
export W3_IID=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"caID": "GiftContract", "caWallet":{"getWalletId": '$W3'}}' http://localhost:9080/api/contract/activate | jq .unContractInstanceId | tr -d '"')
export W4_IID=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"caID": "GiftContract", "caWallet":{"getWalletId": '$W4'}}' http://localhost:9080/api/contract/activate | jq .unContractInstanceId | tr -d '"')
```

To make things more explainable, is there a way for me to disable the automatic creation of the 10 wallets and instead pass how many lovelaces I want the manually created wallets to start with?